# Cell balancing in BMS

Tags: batteries, cell-balancing, bms

I have  questions with respect to cell balancing please help me

1.when this cell balancing will occur is it when charging the battery or when any cell goes more then rated voltage.

2.can you please explain below scenario
if am following passive cell balancing where a resistor is used to discharge the excess voltage of cell
I have 3 cell of maximum voltage that it can store is 5v nominal voltage is 3.3v
1st cell is at 1v
2nd cell is at 3.3v
3rd cell is at 2v
Here when cell one reach 3.3 v the second cell voltage will 5.6v
Which may leads to exposion
In all the above I have connect the cell in series

3.how charging of cell will be done in series connection BMS.)

Comment: Is this a hypothetical question? I'm not aware of a single 3.3 V cell technology that can go up to 5V and isn't irreparably damaged at 1V.

Answer (score 1):

1. It highly depends on the IC you are using. Typicaly balancing is done in the charging cycle.
2. Passive balancing is pretty simple. I am not entirely catching the point of your example so let me try another example. You have 3 batteries in series. Two of them are 3.5V but one is at 3.7V. To balance the battery cell, a resistor will be connected (usually using FETs) in series with the battery cell, thus the current will start to flow from the cell, through the resistor, slowly discharging the battery. The main function of BMS is to protect the battery (sometimes even without passive balancing). Its goal is mainly to detect overvoltage and undervoltage, thus the battery SHOULDN'T explode even without passive balancing, its life span will be shortened though.
3. Not entirely sure what you meant by that. Once you connect the batteries in series and connect the BMS, the device will appear as a simple battery back, but protected. Thus charging will be same, as charging batteries without the BMS.

EDIT: 2. From my answer it may look like it's not neccesary to use cell balancing, which is not how it should've sounded.